# correct way of handling StringIndexOfBoundException

Tags: java

The below code throws me `StringIndexOfBoundException`

```
if (custom.getUser().equals("0") || custom.getUser().equals("")) {
    vital.add(new Pair<String, String>("User", "-"));
} else {
    vital.add(new Pair<String, String>("User", custom.user() + "F" + "\n" + custom.getName().subString(0,1));
}
```

Displaying the first character of the String. The below code is working fine, but i am not sure whether its the correct way of doing it.

```
String name = "";
if (custom.getUser().equals("0") || custom.getUser().equals("")) {
    vital.add(new Pair<String, String>("User", "-"));
} else if (!custom.getName().equals("")) {
    name = custom.getName().substring(0, 1);
} else {
    vital.add(new Pair<String, String>("User", custom.user() + "F" + "\n" + name));
}
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to be valid Java code. Can you show us your actual code, or a simplified version that compiles?

Comment: `String` has `.isEmpty()`!

Comment: Make sure String length() is in the range you are using in subString.

Comment: @TimS. Why is it not valid?

Comment: @arshajii e.g. `new Pair < String` is not something I recognize as valid Java. If I'm mistaken, please let me know what that is.

Comment: @TimS. It's the type parameter (he just added an extra space), e.g. `new ArrayList < String > ()`.

Comment: Ohh, now it's obvious. Thanks. Maybe if I'd seen the definition of `vital` I would've recognized it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, from where do you get the exception?

`custom.getName().subString(0,1)` throws a `StringIndexOfBoundException` only if `custom.getName()` is empty. But if it's empty, the code will not enter the `else` branch, so you can't be getting the exception.

Second, the second way is not equivalent to the first: if `custom.getName()` is neither empty nor `"0"` nothing is added to `vital`.

---

I feel this is an improvement:

```
if (custom.getUser().equals("0") || custom.getUser().isEmpty()) {
    vital.add(new Pair < String, String > ("User", "-"));
} else {
    // limit scope of variable to else-branch
    String name = ""; 
    // check empty string with isEmpty
    if (!custom.getName().isEmpty()) {
        name = custom.getName().substring(0, 1);
    }
    // add a new Pair in any case
    vital.add(new Pair < String, String > 
       ("User", custom.user() + "F" + "\n" + name));
}
```

Comment: I am not able to use isEmpty(), is there any alternative for the same.

Comment: Two: `.equals("")` and `.length()==0`

Comment: so i can use either one of them length or checking for empty string with equals.

Answer (score 0):

You've just got a logic error in the first block. You can enter the block with an empty string (`custom.getName().equals("")`), which means that `custom.getName().length() == 0`. So when you try to get the first character with `substring(0,1)` it throws a `StringIndexOfBoundException`. Just change the conditional to something like this:

```
if (custom.getUser().equals("0") || custom.getName().length() > 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `else if` condition you need to check if the string "custom.getName().length() >= 2".